# Windows Authentication Initialization ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, windows-authentication

In a ASP.net WebForms project, we currently use Forms Authentication, but the client wishes to use Windows Authentication instead. So I've changed the web.config to use Windows authentication. However, the application needs some user input and put in into a session before any webpage can be accessed. We currently do this in the postback of the loginpage.

Since Windows authentication does not have a 'Login' page, how can this be achieved? Should I check on every page it's On_Init event if the session has been set correctly..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a specific data in session available in every single page, the easiest approach would be to have a dedicated **module** that checks the condition in one of early pipeline events where the session is available (the acquire request state event sounds most suitable).

```
public class CustomConditionCheckModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init( HttpApplication context )
    {
        context.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler( acq_req_state );
    }        

    public void acq_req_state( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // check your condition there - the data is in session
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        if ( ... the condition ... )
           Response.Redirect( "~/anonymous.page.aspx" ); 
    }
}
```

Then you also need a page that can be accessed anonymously (you need a section in the `web.config` for this):

```
<location path="anonymous.page.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />  
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could go with **LDAP** (Active Directory Authentication)
 with windows authentication in web.config but if its intranet web application or another way i.e. **role based security** with windows authentication.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Actually, I answered considering windows authentication using LDAP can have custom login page and the rest of things can be achieved in usual ways(as he was doing). Because, I'm also doing in the same way for my current project as I've mentioned. But, if its not like that means client doesn't want that then your is right way.

Comment: You could try to expand your answer.