# Option Strict On does not allow narrowing in implicit type conversions between method and delegate

Tags: vb.net, ihttpmodule

Error: Option Strict On does not allow narrowing in implicit type conversions between method `'context_beginRequest<ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs>'` and delegate `'<BeginRequest>'`

For the code:

```
Public Sub Init(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init
    'context.
    AddHandler context.BeginRequest, New EventHandler(AddressOf context_BeginRequest)
End Sub
```

context_BeginRequest function::

```
Public Sub context_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs)
.....
```

.....
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

That's because [`HttpApplication.BeginRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest) is just of type `EventHandler`... so your second parameter should be of type `EventArgs`, not `WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs`.

Comment: Thanks Jon... But I want to use Identity in the method context_BeginRequest, to check the authentication, which is not present in the System.EventArgs. Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: Well you could use `EventArgs` as the parameter type and *see* if the value is actually a `WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs`, but I wouldn't rely on it if I were you. You can't tell an event raiser to give you extra information just because you want it. (I wouldn't even expect authentication information to be present at that point, to be honest...)

Comment: Really thanks for the suggestion. 
But what is my problem is I am migrating my app from 2.0 to 4.5.
In 4.5 WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate is not supported which is present in global.asax. So I created HttpModule page will handle the events and authentication. So In the global.asax, the method Application_Start can call the begin_request event of the httpmodule and authentication will be done. This is what i want to do... Can you suggest me on this?    For help I am using this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541114/windows-authentication-initialization-asp-net

Comment: @user2323566: I really don't know, I'm afraid - I just answered the question about why the code wasn't compiling...